# From Angular app is there a way to check if bearer token is expired?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, jwt, bearer-token

My question is simple, is there a "good" and applicable way to check when a bearer token is expired from my Angular app?

#### This is my problem:

If I leave the app open in my browser... someone could see what is on my screen (because i am still "tecnically" logged in). Whereas if i implement a log out when token is expired that would not happen.

**Here's what i would want:**

- I do NOT want to check the token when i do API's calls (since i'am already doing that).
- What i want is to let the angular app "automatically" know when the token is expired.

**Here's what i've tried:**

- I tried to create a function that is called every five seconds to check for bearer token expiration but i think this is not a doable solution and will result in performance issues and unclean code.
- What i also did was create an Angular interceptor and intercept any 403 / 401 API's calls but that only solves my problem slightly.
- I am already checking token validity on back-end when an api call is made

---

I scattered online for solutions, and my understanding is that there isn't a "clean" one right now.

Any help here would be apreciated!

Comment: I don't think would be a good idea to have the token validated on the client side. I like to implement idle timeouts into my sensitive projects so it automatically logs out after N minutes. The not so sensitive ones I consider enough to train end users and consider that only one screen won't cause harm as any other request would be refused by the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt there is any out-of-the-box solution for this, as this is a very specific requirement.

I would have a counter in the client side (browser), once this counter reaches zero, proactively logout the user in the client side.

Then the question is, how to set this counter at the first place? You could check every time there is an incoming request (with an Angular http-interceptor) and extract this information from the bearer token. These tokens should include an expiration time ([rfc7519 section-4.1.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#section-4.1.4)). This way if the backend decides to extend the session (increasing the expiration time), you will automatically update the counter and do not logout the user before that happens.

The code would be something similar to this:

```
let previousTimeoutId;

// "expirationTime" is calculated from the incoming JWT Bearer token
function updateLogoutCounter(expirationTime) {
    // remove any previously created "logout" call 
    if(previousTimeoutId) {
        clearTimeout(previousTimeoutId);
    }
    
    // "logoutApp" is the function that triggers the logout in the client side
    previousTimeoutId = setTimeout(logoutApp, expirationTime);
}

// in the http interceptor, call the "updateLogoutCounter" function
```

It seems it is clear for you, but it is important to remind everybody:

- Never trust the client side, Bearer tokens are always checked in the backend.
- Never accept any incoming request with an invalid token.
- It is a good practice to use a library to check the validity of Bearer tokens, to make sure all possible values are correctly verified.
- It is a good practice to use an external service to create these Bearer tokens (IAM, WAF, etc.), to make sure the creation of the JWT is up-to-date and correctly implemented.

Comment: Well, thanks for that! I agree with you, in fact if a user is still using the app (e.g. calling apis) i will renew the token so it doesn't expire. I am checking server side if the token is still valid when calling an API.

Comment: I'll try to implement the timer in the interceptor. Hope that doesn't slow down my app. Thanks!

Comment: I think your solution isn't too bad, except that 5s is a lil too much, maybe every minute? Always remember that it's very hard to avoid user mistakes with pure code....if the user will leave a sensitive tab open they may well write their passwords in a postit and leave it on the screen. I'm a believer that as a developer you should have certain validations in your code but the user training is the msot important part of security....maybe that's a discussion for another topic  =D